# List values transformation

Tags: python, arrays, list, dataframe, numpy

i have a pandas dataframe like this

```
     Adress                           Demand       Coordinates
0   Depot                               10       (40.7484405, -73.985664399)
1   Solomon R. Guggenheim Museum        15       (40.7829796, -73.9589706)
2   Museum of the City of New York      20       (40.7924939, -73.951908899)
3   Rockefeller Center                  15       (40.7587402, -73.9786736)
4   Bryant Park                         10       (40.7535965, -73.9832326)
5   Lower East Side Tenement Museum     20       (40.718818, -73.9900876)
```

also I have three routes in routes like this:

```
routes=[[0, 2, 5 , 0], [0, 4, 3, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
```

how can I get a list with the coordinates for each index in a list instead of the indexes of the dataframe?
something like this:

```
coord_routes=
[[[40.7484405, -73.985664399],
  [40.7924939, -73.951908899],
  [40.718818, -73.9900876],
  [40.7484405, -73.985664399]],
 [[40.7484405, -73.985664399],
  [40.7535965, -73.9832326],
  [40.7924939, -73.951908899],
  [40.7484405, -73.985664399]],
 [[40.7484405, -73.985664399],
  [40.7829796, -73.9589706],
  [40.7484405, -73.985664399]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=["Adress", "Demand", "Coordinates"],
    data=[
        ["Depot", 10, (40.7484405, -73.985664399)],
        ["Solomon R. Guggenheim Museum", 15, (40.7829796, -73.9589706)],
        ["Museum of the City of New York", 20, (40.7924939, -73.951908899)],
        ["Rockefeller Center", 15, (40.7587402, -73.9786736)],
        ["Bryant Park", 10, (40.7535965, -73.9832326)],
        ["Lower East Side Tenement Museum", 20, (40.718818, -73.9900876)],
    ],
)

coord_routes = [df["Coordinates"].iloc[route] for route in routes]
```

You can also add `.tolist()` to `df["Coordinates"].iloc[route]` if you want to get list objects instead.